# FFMpeg - 3:2 Pulldown without interlacing

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 24FPS progressive animation that I'll be burning to a DVD. In parts of the film, there are smooth 60FPS progressive transitions/movements that I need to dub in in post. I want to use 3:2 pulldown to virtually increase the framerate of the source footage, but the telecine filter also goes about interlacing the footage. I need to interlace AFTER I dub in the effects.

In essence, I need every first frame duplicated twice and every second frame duplicated three times to increase the framerate from 24p to 60p. I haven't been able to fathom a command that can do this effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done directly using the fps filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf fps=60 out.mp4
```

This, on its own, will create three copies of the first frame and two copies of the second frame and so on.

If you need to reverse the cadence, two copies of first frame and three copies of second frame, we need to shift timestamps beforehand and restore them later.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf setpts=(N+1)/24/TB,fps=60,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS out.mp4
```